# VirtualBox network settings for multiple isolated virtual machines where only one can access internet

Tags: virtualbox, hacking, intranet, isolated-network

So I want to make a virtual hacking lab using **VirtualBox**. There will be two type of machines.

1. Attack Machine : Kali Linux
2. Target Machine : This can be any type of OS; Ubuntu, CentOS etc.

I want my **attack machine** to have internet access *and* it should be able to communicate with **target machine(s)**. But my target machine(s) **should not** have any access to internet or host OS because most of the time it will contain some **malicious program**. Also these target machines needs a **DHCP server** to assign IPs to them. Basically I want to attack these target machines using my attack machine (kali), want my attack machine to have internet access but not target machines. The target VMs will be downloaded from internet and will have DHCP enabled. Sometimes I might have to give internet access to these target machines so they can update themselves, But that is rare. Its a bit complicated, I couldn't figure out myself so I am asking here.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are hacker who dont how networking on virtualbox works? Create two interfaces on both attack and target. One interface with nat network to connect to inet and another one with internal net between attack and target.

```
inet <nat> attack <internal> target <nat> inet
```

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html configure dhcp server on attack. Enable/disable inet interface on target or plug/unplug virtual cable in virtualbox gui

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For clarification, Target will use **Internal Network** for VM <-> VM communication with no internet connection. Attack machine will use **NAT Network** and not **NAT** for VM <-> VM as well as for **internet** access.

Comment: Both has nat and internal so when you need internet on target you enable interface to nat network on target and disable when not needed